# How to count current user's pages?

Tags: pages, users, count

There are a lot of answers on how to count users posts by using:

```
<?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        global $wpdb;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $where = get_posts_by_author_sql( 'page', true, $user->ID );
    $count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts $where" ); ?>

//option 1
<h2>Hey <?php echo $current_user->display_name ?>, check your page here: {page title with link to page} </h2>

<?php } else { ?>
//option 2
<h2>Welcome <?php echo $current_user->display_name ?>, etc.. text with tags etc.</h2>

<?php } } else { ?>
//option 3
<h2>text with tags etc.</h2>

<?php } ?>
```

But since users can also create pages, how does one get the count of current user's pages in a similar situation as the code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look what `count_user_posts()` does inside and change the post type parameter:

```
global $wpdb;
// 'page' is the important part here
$where = get_posts_by_author_sql('page', true, $userid);
$count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts $where" );
```

Then you change your snippet to:

```
global $wpdb;
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$where = get_posts_by_author_sql( 'page', true, $user->ID );
$count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts $where" );

if ( $count >= 1 ) {

    // echo your text snippet

} else {

    // echo your form

}
```

Comment: Hi Tosho, can you please also explain how to add that code in the above example?

Comment: @tobe See my update. Caveat: I haven’t tested it.

Comment: Great! it works like a charme!

Comment: Hi Toscho, what if I would like to display the page title of that user with link to that page?

Comment: @tobe See my update, just an idea, not tested.

Comment: I am not sure what you are out for now. If you have a new question, just ask a new question. Changing the meaning of the original question is not good.

Comment: Thx for the tip. You are correct. I have submitted a new question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/97043/31765