# How to display page title+link of page created by user

Tags: pages, users, links, title

I want to check if user is logged in and if have created a page. If so, option 1 is shown. This all works fine.

But **how to display page title+link of page created by that user** between {page title with link to page}

See the code below I tested it with no results. As used in the code below, nothing special is showing, only option 1 text (which is good for the user have a page created and is logged in).

```
    <?php
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            global $wpdb;
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $where = get_posts_by_author_sql( 'page', true, $user->ID );
        $count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts $where" );

            if ( $count >= 1 ) { 

            // this part is added to display page title+link created by current user
            foreach ( $results as $result )
                printf( '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a><br>', 
                get_permalink( $result->ID ),
                    esc_html( $result-post_title )
                ); ?>

//option 1
    <h2>Hey <?php echo $current_user->display_name ?>, check your page here: {page title with link to page} </h2>

    <?php } else { ?>
    //option 2
    <h2>Welcome <?php echo $current_user->display_name ?>, etc.. text with tags etc.</h2>

    <?php } } else { ?>
    //option 3
    <h2>text with tags etc.</h2>

    <?php } ?>
```

Any suggetions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To list all pages with title and permalink from one user you need `$wpdb->get_results()`. The following code is based on this answer: [How to count current user's pages?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/96461/73)

First, we move the counter into a separate helper function; we might need it later again:

```
/**
 * Get all post IDs and titles of a type for a user.
 *
 * @param int $user_id
 * @param string $post_type 'page' (default), 'post', attachment, a custom post
 *                          type or 'any' (which excludes attachments)
 * @return array
 */
function t5_user_pages( $user_id, $post_type = 'page' )
{
    global $wpdb;
    $where = get_posts_by_author_sql( $post_type, true, $user_id );
    return $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts $where" );
}
```

Now we use that function in our code:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() )
{
    $user    = wp_get_current_user();
    $results = t5_user_pages( $user->ID );
    $count   = count( $results );

    if ( $count >= 1 )
    {
        print '<h2>Hello ' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '!</h2>
        <p>These are your pages:</p>
        <ul>';

        foreach ( $results as $result )
            printf( '<li><a href="%1$s">%2$s</a></li>',
                get_permalink( $result->ID ),
                esc_html( $result->post_title )
            );

        print '</ul>';
    } else {
        // user is logged in but hasn't written anything
    }
}
else
{
    // user is not logged in
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this shows the page count ("1 page") instead of the page title+link to it.

Comment: @tobe I have tested this code. It does exactly what you have asked for. Make sure to copy the complete example.

Comment: Sry my mistake, I forgot to update line 6 and 7. I also removed the line: `print "<h2>$count pages</h2>";` for I don't need to display the amount of pages. While the page title+link is now showing above the text `<h2>Hey <?php echo $current_user->display_name ?>, check your page here: {page title with link to page} </h2>` But I want to display the page title+link between the {} in that line. If I de add the complete option 1 line here `printf( ' <h2>option 1 text+code</h2> '` then the `<?php echo $current_user->display_name ?>` does not work of course. Is there no <?php ?> I can add between {}

Comment: The second option cannot work, because it will only be used when there is no _known_ user, hence no name.

Comment: Do you mean it not possible to have as result: <h2> hello {current user display name} you can find your page here {page title+link}</h2>

Comment: Found it. See my answer below. If you could edit your answer with the code below, I can accept it as your answer ;-)

Comment: @tobe Oh, finally I understood what you actually wanted. :) I have rewritten my answer and moved the SQL part into a separate function that you can use to count other post types too.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! check the code below:

```
<?php
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $where = get_posts_by_author_sql( 'page', true, $user->ID );
        $count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts $where" );

            if ( $count >= 1 ) { ?>

    //option 1 if user is logged in and have created a page
    // added Toscho's code from answer 1 between second '<? php ?>'
    <h2>Hey <?php echo $current_user->display_name ?>, check your page here: <?php foreach ( $results as $result )
                    printf( '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>',
                    get_permalink( $result->ID ),
                    esc_html( $result->post_title )
                ); ?></h2>

    <?php } else { ?>

    //option 2 if user is logged in, but have not yet submitted a page
    <h2>Welcome <?php echo $current_user->display_name ?>, etc.. text with tags and some form php code</h2>

    <?php } } else { ?>

    //option 3 is no user is not logged in
    <h2>text with tags etc and social login php code</h2>

    <?php } ?>
```